# How to create Emulator for Samsung Galaxy Note2 in android?

Tags: android

I developed an application for Google nexus(720*1280,4.7",Android version 4.0)

but my client device is Samsung Note 2( which is also 720*1280, but 5.5" and Android version is 4.0)

He is saying that the images are getting blurred.

How can I create Emulator to check for Samsung Note.

Is it possible to check my xml's in graphical layout for Samsung Note?

I really cant understand why this change, when both the devices are 720*1280.

Please help me to create Graphical Layout view to check for Samsung Note,and how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Erd2k6EKxCQ

Comment: How can I check my xml for Galaxy Note2 5.5" using graphical layout?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the specs of Note 2 here:

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_note_ii_n7100-4854.php

And then you can create an AVD using basically these values:

- Screen Size 5.55"
- Resolution 720w x 1280h
- Density xhdpi
- RAM 2 GiB

They have the same resolution but as you already said, screen sizes are different which is most likely the reason of your problem.

Comment: Screen density is the culprit, not the different screen size per se.